# How to use form_tag to update params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been struggling with a problem in Rails for a couple of days and still could not find the solution. Could you help me with that?

Problem: I have a search box that puts a :search_string entry in the params structure. I use a form_tag for that and it works fine.

```
<% form_tag :controller=> 'items', :action => 'find' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string, params[:search_string] %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is when I want to add and update other params key-value (in another view), for instance :start_date, to filter the search_string result. Here is the code snipped that I use in the view:

```
<% form_tag :controller=> "items", :action => "find", :params => params do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag  :date_start,  '2010-04-01' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'April' %>
<% end %>

<% form_tag :controller=> "items", :action => "find", :params => params do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag  :date_start,  '2010-03-01' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'March' %>
<% end %>
```

When I first click on "April" submit button, then the params is correctly passed to the controller (i.e. there is a params[:start_date]='April'). However when I try to click "March" button afterwards, the params[:start_date] is not updated. I definitely think this is a stupid newbie mistake, but I cannot figure out how to properly use the form_tag. Could you tell me if I am doing something work? Otherwise, could you advise me which is the best way to update the params using form_tag's ? Thank you very much in advance.

Miquel

Comment: Are you looking for start_date or date_start?

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is instead force-merge the parameters, something along the lines of:

```
<% form_tag :controller=> "items", :action => "find", :params => params.merge(:date_start => '2010-03-01') do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'March' %>
<% end %>
```

There is a chance you're inadvertently submitting two of the same parameter and the first of them is getting picked, but since the "first" is not clearly defined, you may get inconsistent results.

Have a look in your log file to see what parameters are received from the two forms.

Comment: Dear tadman, your tips works fantastically! thanks a lot! I wonder however if there is some kind of "best practices" to deal with passing a large number of key-value pairs from HTTP request to HTTP request. Is the use of params (like I am doing for this application) the best way?

Comment: Sometimes what you need to do is convert your params into hidden fields, though I have not found a way to do this automatically. Technically you want to exclude 'controller', 'action' and 'format' from the params sent over, but this is not always easily accomplished. What you could do is write a helper method that handles the re-encoding of parameters between requests.